# How to fix access localhost (xampp) from internet?

Tags: xampp

I have installed xampp and test my website on localhost. But when I want to access my localhost fro internet, I use my public IP, but it have a problem like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfFkS.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f37So.png)

How can I fix this? This is my router. I don't know is this a mistake  port forwarding or what? Hope you guy help me.

Comment: You are using an invalid certificate that only works on localhost. This is a self-signed certificate that isn't validated by SSL company's like `Geotrust`, `COMODO Ca limited` etc.

Comment: @C0dekid.php That certificate is not "invalid" and it does not "only work on localhost". It is a certificate that cannot be validated in this situation. And you cannot get a certificate that _can_ be validated for this situation. `localhost` is not a domain name a signed certificate can be purchased for, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Either you go on with that self signed certificate and simply "accept" it in your browser (temporary or permanent). Or you have to get a signed certificate, but that requires two requirements: 1. a valid domain name you own and 2. a working name resolution pointing to your IP address.

Comment: @arkascha Well technically it's invalid because he generated the cert on a localhost/not public domain.. or he used the default certificate generated by xampp for testing

Comment: @C0dekid.php Which does not make the certificate "invalid". It just cannot be validated in this situation. That is a difference. Also you do not know if the OP uses such a self signed certificate. That is nowhere said in the question. It could be that the OP _does_ have a signed certificate for some domain name. You should be very careful with assumptions about the OPs situation.

Comment: So how I gonna fix this?

Comment: please tell me how can I fix this?

Comment: I wait answer to long.